# R: Un-escape JSON string and build JSON object

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I am just learning to use the jsonlite library to fetch json data from a server. However in the received json response (whose structure I have no control over), there seems to be a node that I can only describe as a chunk of 'escaped' JSON data, right in the middle of the json object. How do I build a JSON object out of it? I am able to extract each such value OK but then I can't use it as is without turning it into a true JSON object.

example:

```
library(jsonlite)
myFakeJSON <-  '"{"country": "UK","ranking": "45"}"'
json <- toJSON(myFakeJSON)
```

but:

```
> json
[1] "\"{\"country\": \"UK\",\"ranking\": \"45\"}\""
```

The result is not a json object.. What am I doing wrong? How do I escape (or un-escape??) the received data? Seems like something obvious, but not to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making two errors. First: too many quotes, second: wrong test for JSON-hood. If you wanted to use toJSON, then you would give it an R object for conversion rather than a effort at as JSON string.

```
> myFakeJSON <-  '{"country": "UK", "ranking": "45"}'
> fromJSON(myFakeJSON)
$country
[1] "UK"

$ranking
[1] "45"
```

If you just need to remove the extra double-quotes on the "outside" of the curly braces, then this regex replacement succeeds on this small example:

```
> json <- fromJSON(gsub("\\}\\\"", "}", gsub("\\\"\\{","{", myFakeJSON))); json
$country
[1] "UK"

$ranking
[1] "45"
```

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in my question, I have no control of this format. I agree that it has too many quotes etc... but that is what I am receiving. The variable 'myFakeJSON' in the example illustrates the bizarre format and it would be good to see how to deserialize it back into proper JSON without changing the example.

Comment: I'm having to tinker with the regex a bit but for the most part I am starting to be able to get structured objs out of the mess. Thanks! I'm gonna accept this as an answer.